# Weak maximum principle for the p-Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

For the equation $\Delta_p u  = 0 $ in $U$ ($U$ open and bounded), does  a weak maximum principle hold? (The maximum and minimum occur on $\partial U$)? If yes, someone can indicate a book with the theorem?

Thanks in advance ( my english is horrible, sorry ... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. See Theorem 2.15 in [Notes on the p-Laplace equation](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~lqvist/p-laplace.pdf) by Peter Lindqvist. It asserts more: the Comparison Principle holds for the p-Laplacian; the Maximum Principle amounts to comparison with a constant function.

If you wanted to prove it from scratch, you would argue that a $p$-harmonic function is the *unique minimizer* of $p$-energy for its boundary values. Since the truncation by $\sup_{\partial U} u$ does not increase the energy and does not change the boundary values, it has to keep the function the same.

Comment: from the theorem 2.15 can I obtain the weak maximum principle ?

Comment: @LeandroTavares Yes, by letting $v$ be constant function.

Comment: Does it hold for $p=1$ ?